# How do I unpack this error with Mongoose and Promisify?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have this in Mongoose and Promisify

This is the pre save conditions - I check for a pause (which times out) and then add one if all okay

```
//check if there is a pause for this id
HonkSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var query  = Pause.where({ id: this.id }).findOneAsync()
    .then(function(res){
        if(res) {

          var e = new Error('Not 5 Minutes')
          next(e)
        }//else {
          next()
        //}
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
      var err = new Error(err);
      next(err);
    })
});

//Add pause
HonkSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  Pause.createAsync({id: this.id})
    .then(function(res){
      next()
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
      var err = new Error(err);
      next(err);
    })
});
```

I create a new one like this

```
// Creates a new Honk in the DB
export function create(req, res) {
  Honk.createAsync(req.body)
    .then(responseWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res, 412));
}
```

And handleError does this

```
function handleError(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 500;
  return function(err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(statusCode).send(JSON.stringify(err));
  };
}
```

The log message above gives this

```
{ [Error: Not 5 Minutes] cause: [Error: Not 5 Minutes], isOperational: true }
```

But the error message to the client is this

```
{"cause":{},"isOperational":true}
```

So my question is, how do I get a meaningful message into the client?

Comment: FWIW, Mongoose already supports [promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) out of the box. Also, what _exactly_ do you want to return to the client? A text string, a JSON object, ...?

Comment: I was thinking a JSON object with an error field. I'll pull out all the promisify stuff and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
return res.status(statusCode).send({ error : err.message });
```

Comment: I see. I thought all the promises had bundled up the result but it is just the Error object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Found That error in findOne query find more then one result means it is operational error.